# In linux, how can I convert a root user to a less privileged user keeping all files and settings?

Tags: linux

In linux, how can I convert a **root user** to a **less privileged user** keeping all files and settings?

Comment: There's no "a root user"; the user `root` has a special role, and most system files belong to root. There may be other "system administrator" user (there are various ways of setting them up) with personal files, do you mean those? Or do you mean "I accidentally did daily work logged in as root, now I want to add a proper non-root user, and give it those files"?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *the* root user, because there is only one, you can't without very likely breaking your system completely. A lot of things during boot need to run as the root user, for example.

If you mean a user with *`sudo` access* you can check the `sudo` configuration by running `visudo` with superuser privileges and either

1. remove the relevant entry in that file giving specifically that user some access or
2. remove the *group* listed in the `sudo` configuration from the user with `vigr` (again with superuser privileges). The name of this group varies, but "wheel" and "sudo" are common.